# How to generate a random number in java with array bounds?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I want to ask how to generate a random number in java , i know it is done by random.nextint() but i want to check if the number is not what i wanted then it should be rejected and a new random number should be generated .

I want something like this :

```
Integer[] in = {1,2,3,4,5};    
int a = new Random().nextInt(10);
for(int i=0;i<in.length ;i++)
   if(a==in[i])
      //new random number
```

if the number is present in the above array (in) then new random number should be generated

Answer (score 2):

Just put it in a do-while loop:

```
int a;
do {
    a = new Random().nextInt(10);
} while (Arrays.asList(in).contains(a));
```

Comment: I guess it depends how his for loop is supposed to go, if it supposed to iterate even if he didn't get his value then your solution won't be what he needs, otherwise your solution is solid.

Comment: It looks like OP is using the for loop as his "contains" method

Comment: May also want to consider creating the set of rejected values *once*, and creating them as a *Set* rather than a List or array.

Comment: Perhaps this should be a do / while loop as you always want a new random number.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid not generating a number you didn't want in the first place.

You can do either

```
int a = random.nextInt(5);
if (a > 0) a += 5;
```

or use a selection

```
int[] valid = { 0, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; // 0 to 9 but not 1,2,3,4,5
int a = valid[random.nextInt(valid.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the method again. That is, if the number generated fits the if criteria then call a = new Random().nextInt(10);

Or, if your for loop ever regenerates a random number, you could just have the if statement do nothing ex: if(xyz){}; which of course would be pointless, and I think the original solution is probably what you seek.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any loops and retrying, try this:

```
    int [] in = {1,2,3,4,5};
    // generate integers from 0 up to the size of your array of allowed numbers:
    int index = new Random().nextInt(in.length); 
    int a = in[index]; // use the random integer as index for your array of allowed numbers
```